# Recreating a conda env from file fails with Errno 13: Permission denied 'WHEEL'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, conda

So I ran `conda env create -n testing_env -f previous_env.yml`...

It found a bunch of cached packages, which is all right since I have tried to install similar packages before, I guess? But it fails at `pyparsing 3.0.9` with complaints about a 'WHEEL' permission.

```
...
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.1 in ${HOME}/miniconda3/envs/TEST/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from g2p-en==2.1.0->-r ${PROJECT_FOLDER}/condaenv.2hu3w9vt.requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.21.2)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.7.4.3 in ${HOME}/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from huggingface-hub==0.4.0->-r ${PROJECT_FOLDER}/condaenv.2hu3w9vt.requirements.txt (line 7)) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages (from numba==0.50.1->-r ${PROJECT_FOLDER}/condaenv.2hu3w9vt.requirements.txt (line 16)) (67.7.2)
...
Installing collected packages: ws4py, ..., g2p-en, librosa
  Attempting uninstall: pyparsing
    Found existing installation: pyparsing 3.0.9
    Uninstalling pyparsing-3.0.9:

Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'WHEEL'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I've seen [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60663386/) but those denied permissions to a specific path. I didn't know where to find 'WHEEL' to check these permissions. I guess I could try installing pyparsing manually later, but I don't think that's the root of the issue.

Has anyone seen something similar before?

Comment: Also, why is it looking in so many different directories for requirements? I want it to avoid using cache if possible, but I haven't seen a way to pass `--no-cache` as a pip argument to this conda command yet.